# Unit Test Case For Spring jdbc template for RowMapper

Tags: arrays, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, jdbc

I know it is not a good thing write a unit test for mapper or get set but, it is what it is, so I am stucked how to do unit test for mappers;

StudentGroupList below;

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class StudentGroupList {

 private String studentId;
}
```

StudentGroupListRowMapper below;

```
public class StudentGroupListRowMapper implements RowMapper<StudentGroupList> {

  @Override
  public StudentGroupList mapRow(Resultset rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

  StudentGroupList studentGroupList = new StudentGroupList();
 
  studentGroupList.setStudentId(rs.getString("student_id"));

  return studentGroupList;
 }
}
```

I have tried below, but jococo coverage test did not coverage anything

```
   public class TaskGroupListRowMapperTest {

     private ResultSet resultSet;
     private StudentGroupList studentGroupList;

     @Before
     public void setUp() {
     resultSet = mock(ResultSet.class);
     studentGroupList = mock(StudentGroupList.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testStudentGroupListMapper() throws SQLException {
     when(resultSet.getString("student_id"))
    .thenReturn(studentGroupList.getStudentID());
     
    assertTrue(studentGroupList.getStudentId(), true);
    
 }
}
```

İt says exception; thenReturn() may be missing.

Comment: I mean DAO layer is usually not tested but it is a big improvement since last time (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63001810/how-to-test-constructor-with-arraylist-in-junit-4?noredirect=1#comment111411493_63001810) when you wanted to test a constructor, so not so bad:) You are still gonna get minus votes (not from me, but still) because you are not asking for help with a specific question you just want us to write tests for you

Comment: thank you for your answer but next time I can write my test myself because I never wrote Unit test for mapper

Comment: @JAsgarow please see my updated answer

Comment: That test class totally doesn't make any sense. Why on earth does it implement `RowMapper`? You want to test the `StudentGroupListRowMapper` then test it. Currently you are testing nothing (which is also what Jacoco is telling you!). Create a mock for the `ResultSet` (use something like Mockito). Call the method on the rowmapper and assert that the result is proper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take it easy, we were all there in the past and try to understand what a unit test is supposed to do.

- You don't unit test everything just for the sake of unit test coverage. When you have a framework callback like RowMapper, it is one of those cases. Your `StudentGroupListRowMapper` is very simple, so an integration test for your Dao will cover it. Anyway, you want to unit test so just think of it as a simple class and let's go through the steps.
- You want to create the instance of the class you want to test and also provide mock dependencies for any services it calls. Luckily your `StudentGroupListRowMapper` does not call anything. **Since the method you want to test is** `StudentGroupList mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)`, you have to decide if you can provide a `ResultSet` and a `rowNum`. Since `ResultSet` is not something you create, your provide a mock for that

```
    ResultSet inputRs = mock(ResultSet.class);
    int rowNum = 1;
```

- Now when your method executes, it is going call `inputRs.getString("student_id")` to get student id but it is mock and it doesn't know what to return so you have to tell your mock what to do when `inputRs.getString("student_id")` is called

```
   when(inputRs.getString("student_id")).thenReturn("student-id-1");
```

- Now you know your expected `StudentGroupList` should be created with `"student-id-1"` and should be returned from the method.

`assertEquals(resultedStudentGroupList.getStudentId(),"student-id-1");`

- Lets combine all of them together.

```
   public class StudentGroupListRowMapperTest {

    StudentGroupListRowMapper mapper = new StudentGroupListRowMapper();
 
    @Test
    public void testMapRow() {
      ResultSet inputRs = mock(ResultSet.class);
      int rowNum = 1;
      when(inputRs.getString("student_id")).thenReturn("student-id-1");

      StudentGroupList result = mapper.mapRow(inputRs, rowNum);

      assertEquals(result.getStudentId(), "student-id-1");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much supper explanation. Lets says that I have 8 or 9 rows let say; I have student name, surname etc.. Do I have to put int rowNum 8 sth

Comment: That is for integration test. The method you are testing `mapRow` only cares about how to map a single row. It does not care about how many rows were retuned or what is the total result from the dao. When you unit test, just forget about everything, just think about what is the input and what are things, it does inside that method

Comment: what about timestamp ? I mean I have tried with when(inputRs.getTimeStamp("student_date").toLocalDateTime()).thenReturn(LocalDateTime.of(2019,2,14,6,11)));                                                          assertEquals(result.getStudentDate, LocalDateTime.of(2019,2,14,6,11));   I got null pointer exception